# My brand new MacBook Book Pro dies at 30% with no warning

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I got my MBP earlier today and when I'm using it it works just fine but when it dies it gives me no warning and it dies around 30%, I don't know how to fix this issue as it's supposed to have a 10 hour battery life but when I charge to maybe 60 or 70 it just dies at 30 in an hour and a half or two, and when I charge it it begins at around 30-40, what does this mean and is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Please post the data in about this Mac -> system report-> hardware -> power -> battery. Also, if it's an old battery, I presume battery replacement. If it is brand new, it should be charged to full then down to 50 and back to 100 for some days.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, how long your MacBook Pro will last on a charge will depend on a number of factors, including what you're using it for at the time. Most people most of the time will not achieve 10hrs in between charges. Sometimes you will, and sometimes you'll even exceed 10hrs, but usually you'll fall short of that.

However, it also shouldn't just die at 30%, so I would reset the System Management Controller (SMC).

**Resetting the SMC on a MacBook Pro (2018 or 2019 models)**

NOTE: If your MBP is not a 2018 or 2019 model with the T2 chip, please let me know so these steps can be amended.

1. **Fully shut down your MBP.**
2. Press and hold the power button for at least 10 seconds
3. Let go of the power button and wait 5 seconds
4. Power up your MBP again

Once you've reset the SMC fully charge your MBP and see how you go. If it's still misbehaving, reset the SMC again but with the following steps instead:

1. **Fully shut down your MBP.**
2. Press and hold the **right** <kbd>shift</kbd> key and the **left** <kbd>option</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd> keys for 7 seconds before then also pressing and holding the power button (or Touch ID button) down for another 7 seconds (i.e. the keys will end up being held down for 14 seconds, the power button for 7 seconds)
3. Let go of all three keys and the power button
4. Wait 5 seconds
5. Power up your MBP again

Now test your MBP again.

Answer (score 1):

If you experience any hardware problems with a brand new Mac, take it back to the shop for repair, replacement or refund.